# What could prevent establishing a connection between two web api apps in Azure?

Tags: c#, azure, asp.net-web-api

I have two web API apps (App Service resources) in Azure: **app1** and **app2**.  I'm trying to send `https` requests from *app1* to *app2* but connections fail with this error:

> "An error occurred while sending the request. Unable to read data
>   from the transport connection: An existing connection was forcibly
>   closed by the remote host"

When I run app1 on my local dev machine (e.g. from `VS 2017`) I can connect to app2 in Azure with no problems.

I use the following code to `POST` a request from *app1* to *app2*:

```
using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
{
    HttpResponseMessage response = await client.PostAsync(uri, stringContent);
}
```

Comment: Does this happen intermittently or all the time? Has it ever worked?

Comment: What is the value of `uri`?

Comment: @MehdiIbrahim It happens all the time.  It never worked.

Comment: @juunas: I cannot disclose the full uri at the moment.  Example of a uri format: https://<subdomain>.azurewebsites.net/api/aux/seed.  The same uri works fine from my dev machine which is not in Azure.

Comment: Yeah, I just wanted to know you are actually calling the proper URL and not localhost or something :)

Answer (score 0):

1. Is StringContent huge?
2. Or is the API you are consuming doing any processing that is tanking your resources?
3. Are there multiple concurrent requests - e.g. are you calling the API asynchronously or with multiple threads in a loop?

The error indicates that a connection is successful but there's something wrong with the API. In my past experience, I've run into this problem when the API's host was running low on memory and high on CPU. Some of the items above could cause this.

Try invoking the API with an empty string parameter.

Comment: At the moment I'm trying a single API and a very small string content - less than 20 chars.  No other requests are being sent to app2 from anywhere else.  Again, calling the same api from outside of Azure woks fine.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same situation (App Service A calling App Service B) and finally found the problem.

In SSL Settings of App Service B, I had to lower `Minimum TLS Version` to 1.0.

Of course it would be better to make App Service A use a higher TLS version, but I am unsure how to set this.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you cannot use the default address for the service. It uses azuresites.net SSL cert which I could not get to work. As soon as I created my own url and ssl cert, it worked fine.